# subtract columns in a table with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by, sum

I need to subtract one column from another column in a table in my database by using LINQ

Table trial

```
Userid  Money     Type

x       500       +

y       250       +

x       300       -

y       100       -

x       120       -
```

I need to do this;

`500 - 300 - 120` for x

and

`250 - 100` for y.

how do i do that?

I tried grouping like `trial.userid` and `trial.money`, `trial.type`.
Basically, I think i have to group the users via id's and i need to add the + and subtract - from the sum of the addition
please aid me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like:

```
var query = from row in db.Rows
            group row by row.UserId into tmp
            select new {
              UserId = tmp.Key,
              Money = tmp.Sum(x => x.Type == '+' ? x.Money : -x.Money)
            };
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this for each group:

```
group.Sum(row => row.Type == "+" ? row.Money : -row.Money)
```